# Sending POST data from Codeigniter controller

Tags: codeigniter, controller, e-commerce, payment-gateway

I am currently developing a small shopping cart where payment options are `cash on delivery` and other prepaid payment options using a `payment gateway`. Now my cart's flow chart is like

1. Places order,enters address
2. Selects payment options ( COD or Prepaid )
3. If COD confirm order
4. If prepaid, redirect to the payment gateway page

So when the customer selects an option , the controller function `handlePayment()` checks if its `COD` or `Prepaid`. If its `COD` it shows a view page, or if its `prepaid`, it should redirect to the payment gateway with all necessary data in `POST`.

So how will I be able to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write if COD then $this->view->load('pagename); else you have to call another function $this->functionname($_POST);

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Its a rough assumption of what you need:

```
function handlePayment(){
    if($this->input->post('type') == "COD"){
        $data   = array();
        $data   = $this->input->post(null);
        $this->load->view('cod', $data);
    }else if($this->input->post('type') == "prepaid"){
        $data   = array();
        $data   = $this->input->post(null);
        $this->prepaidPayment($data);  
    }
}

function prepaidPayment($data){
    //do something with the data which contains all the post variables
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**different angle -- can you ask them the COD or Prepaid question -- first?** 
and then make each 'path' completely separate.
Long term that could be better for your application especially if it grows.
and might help if you can do more stringent form validation on the Prepaid track, 
( like if some of that information is used as part of the credit card validation ) 
versus COD where the payment happens in person